# DB Re-index failure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm managing a DB (SQL Server 2008) with a two step SQL Agent job that is triggered to initiate a DB Re-index. However on the second step the SQL Agent job fails. Where can I find logs that detail the cause of the failure? The name of the Db instance is: 2015_NBAPLAYOFFS. 
Should I be concerned with this naming convention?

Below is the two step SQL job.

Verify DB in mirrored state

```
DECLARE @status int select @status=mirroring_role from sys.database_mirroring where database_id = db_id('2015_NBAPLAYOFFS') 
IF @status = 2  BEGIN       
RAISERROR ('Database is in mirror state - No EVS Maintenance plan', 16,1);
END
```

DB Re-Index

```
set lock_timeout 120000
USE 2015_NBAPLAYOFFS
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255), @IndexName varchar(255)
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR select I.name, '[' + schema_NAME(o.uid)+ '].[' + O.name + ']' from sysindexes I, sysobjects O where I.id=O.id AND O.xtype='U' and indid = 1
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @IndexName, @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT convert(varchar(50), Getdate(),121) + ' - Reindexing ' + @TableName
EXECUTE ('ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON ' + @TableName + ' REBUILD')
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @IndexName, @TableName
End
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the rules for identifiers as documented in Books Online:

> The first character must be one of the following:
>
> 1. A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
> 2. The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).

I don't recommend using any character from bullet #2 anywhere in a database name, except maybe an underscore, and even then, not as the leading character.

When you have a database name that starts with a number, and you run this:

```
USE 2015_NBAPLAYOFFS;
```

You'll get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
> Incorrect syntax near '2015'.

You can find this error in the job history (maybe - steps with a lot of verbose output may actually get truncated).

```
SELECT TOP (1) message
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
  WHERE run_status = 0
    AND sql_message_id > 0
    AND step_id > 0
ORDER BY run_date DESC, run_time DESC;
```

For me, I get this:

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$InstanceName. Incorrect syntax near '2015'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.

You can get around this using proper name quoting, e.g.:

```
USE [2015_NBAPLAYOFFS];
```

But you're much better off renaming the database, following the rules. Why not just `NBAPLAYOFFS`? Are you really going to create a new database every year? Why? If so, then why not `NBAPLAYOFFS_2015`? At least that way the NBA playoffs databases will sort together, instead of all the 2015 sports, then all the 2016 sports, etc.

Oh, and [I fully agree with @Kin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103560/1186), you are not going about rebuilding in the most efficient way. Better tools than your script already exist, you just need to copy them.

Comment: Ideally I would have named the Db as you suggested… but I playing the cleanup role on this one. Someone decided on the name before my arrival. Thanks very much for the positive feedback

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @Aaron said :

> Where can I find logs that detail the cause of the failure?

You have to have sql agent log output to a file as below or use [T-SQL to find out from jobhistory table](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1054/failed-sql-server-agent-jobs/):

[image]

Also, you should understand that [there is a cost to reinventing the wheel](http://thebertrandfamily.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/), why not use existing - well tested worldwide Solution [Ola's - SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance](http://SQL%20Server%20Index%20and%20Statistics%20Maintenance)

**Your script has a major drawback, since it will rebuild all the indexes - irrespective of their fragmentation level, page count, etc.** This will lead to a huge transaction log that can impact your mirroring (Disaster recovery). The above solution is much more mature as it is customizable - e.g. rebuilds indexes which have more than 30% fragmentation, between 10% and 30% does a index reorganize and less than 10% - does nothing. *There are many more benefits of using Ola's solution that you can read on the link above.*

Comment: Thanks all for the positive feedback. This has been really helpful.